# RFC compliant FTP server in Java

Tags: java, mysql, ftp, virtual-directory

I'm looking for a correct implementation of a FTP server (RFC compliant).
I need to change the code for the root directory.

**The use case:** 
All users have their own files. Users are also members of groups that have their own files.

**Idea:** The root directory is only an overview of the group folder + own files. The credentials are in a MySQL database

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: As a starting point, you might see if Apache's [FtpServer](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/index.html) code can some of your needs.